# Access violation executing location when creating Vulkan swapchain using the C++ bindings

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to learn Vulkan using the C++ [vulkan-hpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp) bindings. I'm going through the Vulkan tutorial and used the [RAII Samples](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/tree/master/RAII_Samples) to understand the basics and how to setup a simple app that renders a triangle.
However, when I try to create the swapchain I've encountered this error:

> 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000

The debugger shows that this is called during the constructor of `SwapchainKHR` class (specifically on line 9337 of the [vulkan_raii](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/master/vulkan/vulkan_raii.hpp) header file).

Looking around I've seen similar errors due to the missing extensions for creating the swapchain, but in my code I made sure that I added them and initialized the logical devices using them. Enabling validation layers also doesn't help as they don't seem to catch the error.
Here is a full working examples that reproduces the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>
#include <vulkan/vulkan_raii.hpp>

vk::SurfaceFormatKHR chooseSwapSurfaceFormat(const std::vector<vk::SurfaceFormatKHR> &formatsList)
{
    for (vk::SurfaceFormatKHR const &availableFormat : formatsList)
    {
        if (availableFormat.format == vk::Format::eB8G8R8A8Srgb && availableFormat.colorSpace == vk::ColorSpaceKHR::eSrgbNonlinear)
            return availableFormat;
    }

    return formatsList.front();
}


vk::Extent2D chooseSwapExtent(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, const vk::SurfaceCapabilitiesKHR &surfaceCapabilities)
{
    vk::Extent2D swapchainExtent;
    if (surfaceCapabilities.currentExtent.width == std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max())
    {
        // If the surface size is undefined, the size is set to the size of the images requested.
        swapchainExtent.width = std::clamp(width, surfaceCapabilities.minImageExtent.width, surfaceCapabilities.maxImageExtent.width);
        swapchainExtent.height = std::clamp(height, surfaceCapabilities.minImageExtent.height, surfaceCapabilities.maxImageExtent.height);
    }
    else
    {
        // If the surface size is defined, the swap chain size must match
        swapchainExtent = surfaceCapabilities.currentExtent;
    }

    return swapchainExtent;
}

void findGraphicsAndPresentQueueFamilyIndices(std::vector<vk::QueueFamilyProperties> const &queueFamilyProperties,
                                                uint32_t &graphicsIndex, uint32_t &presentIndex,
                                                const vk::raii::PhysicalDevice &gpu,
                                                const vk::raii::SurfaceKHR &surface)
{
    auto graphicsQueueFamilyProperty =
        std::find_if(queueFamilyProperties.begin(),
                        queueFamilyProperties.end(),
                        [](vk::QueueFamilyProperties const &qfp)
                        { return qfp.queueFlags & vk::QueueFlagBits::eGraphics; });
    assert(graphicsQueueFamilyProperty != queueFamilyProperties.end());
    uint32_t graphicsQueueFamilyIndex = static_cast<uint32_t>(std::distance(queueFamilyProperties.begin(), graphicsQueueFamilyProperty));
    graphicsIndex = graphicsQueueFamilyIndex;
    // get present family index
    uint32_t presentQueueFamilyIndex = gpu.getSurfaceSupportKHR(graphicsIndex, *surface) ? graphicsIndex : static_cast<uint32_t>(queueFamilyProperties.size());

    if (presentQueueFamilyIndex == queueFamilyProperties.size())
    {
        // the graphicsQueueFamilyIndex doesn't support present -> look for an other family index that supports both
        // graphics and present
        for (size_t i = 0; i < queueFamilyProperties.size(); i++)
        {
            if ((queueFamilyProperties[i].queueFlags & vk::QueueFlagBits::eGraphics) &&
                gpu.getSurfaceSupportKHR(static_cast<uint32_t>(i), *surface))
            {
                graphicsQueueFamilyIndex = static_cast<uint32_t>(i);
                presentQueueFamilyIndex = graphicsIndex;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (presentQueueFamilyIndex == queueFamilyProperties.size())
    {
        // there's nothing like a single family index that supports both graphics and present -> look for an other
        // family index that supports present
        for (size_t i = 0; i < queueFamilyProperties.size(); i++)
        {
            if (gpu.getSurfaceSupportKHR(static_cast<uint32_t>(i), *surface))
            {
                presentQueueFamilyIndex = static_cast<uint32_t>(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ((graphicsQueueFamilyIndex == queueFamilyProperties.size()) || (presentQueueFamilyIndex == queueFamilyProperties.size()))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not find a queue for graphics or present -> terminating");
    }

    graphicsIndex = graphicsQueueFamilyIndex;
    presentIndex = presentQueueFamilyIndex;
}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    auto window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan", nullptr, nullptr);

    vk::raii::Context raiContext;

    // get all extensions required by glfw
    uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
    const char **glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

    std::vector<char const *> instanceExtensionNames(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);
    instanceExtensionNames.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME);

    std::vector<char const *> deviceExtensionNames;
    deviceExtensionNames.push_back(VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME);

    // create instance
    vk::ApplicationInfo appInfo("VulkanTest", 1, "Vulkan", VK_API_VERSION_1_1);
    vk::InstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo({}, &appInfo, {}, instanceExtensionNames);
    
    auto instance = vk::raii::Instance(raiContext, instanceCreateInfo);
    // create window surface
    VkSurfaceKHR _surface;
    if (glfwCreateWindowSurface(static_cast<VkInstance>(*instance), window, nullptr, &_surface) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create window surface!");
    
    vk::raii::SurfaceKHR surface (instance, _surface);

    // select physical device
    auto gpu = vk::raii::PhysicalDevice(std::move(instance.enumeratePhysicalDevices().front()));
    
    // get graphics and present index
    auto queueFamilies = gpu.getQueueFamilyProperties();
    uint32_t graphicsIndex = -1;
    uint32_t presentIndex = -1;
    
    findGraphicsAndPresentQueueFamilyIndices(queueFamilies, graphicsIndex, presentIndex, gpu, surface);
    
    if(graphicsIndex < 0 || presentIndex < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot find a valid graphics or present queue");

    // create logical device
    float queuePriority = 0.0f;
    auto deviceQueueCreateInfo = vk::DeviceQueueCreateInfo(vk::DeviceQueueCreateFlags(), static_cast<uint32_t>(graphicsIndex), 1, &queuePriority);
    vk::DeviceCreateInfo deviceCreateInfo(vk::DeviceCreateFlags(), deviceQueueCreateInfo, {}, deviceExtensionNames, nullptr);
    auto device = gpu.createDevice(vk::DeviceCreateInfo(vk::DeviceCreateFlags(), deviceQueueCreateInfo));

    // create swap chain
    std::vector<vk::SurfaceFormatKHR> formats = gpu.getSurfaceFormatsKHR(*surface);
    assert(!formats.empty());
    int windowWidth, windowHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
    vk::SurfaceCapabilitiesKHR surfaceCapabilities = gpu.getSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(*surface);
    vk::Extent2D swapChainExtent = chooseSwapExtent(windowWidth, windowHeight, surfaceCapabilities);
    vk::SurfaceFormatKHR surfaceFormat = chooseSwapSurfaceFormat(formats);
    vk::PresentModeKHR presentMode = vk::PresentModeKHR::eFifo;

    uint32_t imageCount = surfaceCapabilities.minImageCount + 1;

    if (surfaceCapabilities.maxImageCount > 0 && imageCount > surfaceCapabilities.maxImageCount)
    {
        imageCount = surfaceCapabilities.maxImageCount;
    }

    // not using constructor for clarity
    vk::SwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapChainCreateInfo;
    swapChainCreateInfo.setFlags(vk::SwapchainCreateFlagsKHR());
    swapChainCreateInfo.setSurface(*surface);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setMinImageCount(imageCount);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setImageFormat(surfaceFormat.format);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setImageColorSpace(surfaceFormat.colorSpace);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setImageExtent(swapChainExtent);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setImageArrayLayers(1);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setImageUsage(vk::ImageUsageFlagBits::eColorAttachment);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setImageSharingMode(vk::SharingMode::eExclusive);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setPreTransform(surfaceCapabilities.currentTransform);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setCompositeAlpha(vk::CompositeAlphaFlagBitsKHR::eOpaque);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setPresentMode(presentMode);
    swapChainCreateInfo.setClipped(true);

    vk::raii::SwapchainKHR swapChain( device, swapChainCreateInfo );
    
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a call of `nullptr` function pointer. Most likely missing or failed `vkGet*ProcAddr`. Locate the exact call point and it should be obvious. Don't link to external resources here unless you have to and include them inline in your question. Or at least link a permalink to the appropriate commit hash and code line and not to `master`.

Comment: If your line number is still valid, then it looks like bad `VkAllocationCallbacks` passed to `vkCreateIOSSurfaceMVK`